# How to display an array of objects as will?

Tags: matlab

I have defined a class like

```
classdef Test
properties
    a 
    b
end

methods
    function this = Test(a, b)
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    end

    function disp(this)
        fprintf('a=%d b=%d\n', this.a, this.b);
    end
end


end
```

But when I want to display a vector of `Test`, it seems not print each elements of array using the `disp` function just defined.

```
>> out = [Test(1,2),Test(3,4)]
  out = 
    a=1 b=3
    a=2 b=4
```

The questions is how to display an array of objects appropriately? Is there a way to overload the `disp` function and print as the following:

```
out=
   a=1 b=2
   a=3 b=4
```

(In my considering , the output will be same as calling `disp` function to element of array one by one.. But the output seems like firstly print all the a's value `1 3` and then b's value `2 4`.)

Comment: So, what output do you expect? From my point of view, everything seems to be output correctly - or better: as coded.

Comment: In my considering the output will be a=1 b=2 \n a=3 b=4 as the same way as calling `disp` function to elements of array one by one.

Comment: Ah, I haven't seen the "switching" of 2 and 3, I'm sorry. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this result because in your statement `out = [Test(1,2),Test(3,4)]`, the variable `out` becomes an array of the same class `Test`, but of size [1x2].

If you try `out.a` in your console, you'll get:

```
>> out.a
ans =
     1
ans =
     3
```

This is a coma separated list of all the values of `a` in the `out` array. This is also the first parameter that your custom `disp` function sees. It then sees another column vector of all the values of `b`. To understand what the function `fprintf` is presented with you can also try in your console:

```
>> [out.a,out.b]
ans =
     1     3     2     4
>> [out.a;out.b]
ans =
     1     3
     2     4
```

Since `fprintf` works in column major order, it will consume all the values column wise first. In that case we can see that the last option we tried seems better.

Indeed, if you change your `disp` function to:

```
function disp(this)
    fprintf('a=%d b=%d\n', [this.a ; this.b]);
end
```

You get the desired output:

```
>> out = [Test(1,2),Test(3,4),Test(5,6)]
out = 
a=1 b=2
a=3 b=4
a=5 b=6
```

Whichever size of object array you define. Just keep in mind that if you input an array of `Test` object they will be considered column wise:

```
>> out = [ Test(1,2),Test(3,4) ; Test(5,6),Test(7,8) ]
out = 
a=1 b=2
a=5 b=6
a=3 b=4
a=7 b=8
```

---

Last option, if you want even more granularity over the display of your object array, you can customise it the way you like inside the `disp` function:

```
    function disp(this)
        nElem = numel(this) ;
        if nElem==1
            fprintf('a=%d b=%d\n', this.a , this.b );
        else
           for k=1:nElem
                fprintf('a=%d b=%d\n', this(k).a , this(k).b);
            end
        end
    end
```

This produces the same display than before, but since the elements are treated one by one, you could customise even further without having to consider the way arrays are treated by `fprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

With the syntax you use, you should overload the `display` function instead of the `disp` function.

See the (not that simple to read) [corresponding page](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/displaying-objects-in-the-command-window.html) in the documentation.